# Does Parse Server have a default request timeout?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I assumed that Parse Server had a 30s request timeout, but maybe that was for hosted Parse.com and has since been removed in open source Parse Server.

I couldn't find any timeout reference in Parse Server code. From this I would infer that Parse Server itself does hot have a request timeout, neither for `/classes` nor for `/functions` request or within Cloud Code.

The request timeout therefore is only determined by the server, e.g. with express the timeout can be set to 30 seconds like so:

```
const httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.setTimeout(30 * 1000);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

In addition, according to this [Nodejs PR](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/27558), from Nodejs 13 onwards http does not have a default timeout anymore. So without manually setting a timeout, also http server would not have a default timeout. The timeout would then practically be determined by other components in the architecture such as nginx, load balancer, etc.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: Thanks @DaviMacêdo If you want to write an answer I will accept it.